# full text index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In my MySQL table, I want to search two fields using match against method. I have two fields to search but there are different scenarios for searching.

1. Only field1
2. Only field2
3. field1 and field2

I created separate full text index for field1 and field 2, but when I search both fields using match against, no indexes are used. Then I tried creating one more combined index using field1 and field2.

Then it started using that index for searching both those fields. But now I have 3 full text indexes.

Is there any better way to manage this?

Comment: I think you solution is good. Otherwise you can try to use fulltext search on one field and **LIKE** search on another field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using search operation extensively you can consider [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)